# Convert list with several data types (strings, NULL values and ints) into list of floats

Tags: python-3.x, type-conversion

Have a list of list of this kind: [NULL, NULL, NULL, '3', NULL, 0.0, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, '2', '5']. Sometimes I get different order of values in list and using slices or indexes is not a good idea. Cant convert it into list of floats with:

```
for d in attrs:
        try:
            d = float(d)
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            pass
```

I need to have all strings or ints in this list to be floats, and leave NULL as it is...

```
[NULL, NULL, NULL, 3.0, NULL, 0.0, 0.0, NULL, 0.0, NULL, 0.0, NULL, 2.0, 5.0]
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the changes reflect in the original array, we copy the contents of our newly created list b to a.

```
b = []

for each in a:
   try:
      b.append(float(each))
   except Exception as e:
      b.append(each)
a = list(b)
```

Comment: Here a is your attrs (original list)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Thank you @Subrahmanyam Penamakuri, thats rather elegant solution... But I'd also ask for an explanation. What for do we need here a = list(b)?

Comment: To make the changes reflect in the original array, we copy the contents of our newly created list b to a.